# Moodle Submission using API

Tags: php, moodle

Will it be possible to submit an Assignment in Moodle using any of the API's provided by Moodle? I am creating a custom form for submission but I could not find any method which I could use to store the submissions

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to submit the assignment from an external application through web service API. If this is the case then, please have a look at http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Assignment_Web_Services

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this information can help you with your concerns.

```
Using the File API in Moodle forms:
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_the_File_API_in_Moodle_forms
```

Web Forms in moodle are created using forms API. Form API supports all html elements (checkbox, radio, textbox etc), with improved accessibility and security.

```
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Form_API
```

Regards,